# Finding the max island size SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Current sql code will sum up all the max island sizes into one. I'm trying to only find what the max island size is for ***consecutive* hours** Ignoring minutes and seconds within the datetime.

```
 select deviceid, grp -- min(readdate) as mn, max(readdate) as mx
       from (  select deviceid, readdate, sum(case when prev_rd >= readdate - interval '1 hour' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by deviceid order by readdate rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
               from (
                    select deviceid, readdate, lag(readdate) over (partition by deviceid order by readdate) as prev_rd
                    from metersWithExcess
                    order by readdate)
            ) tt
            group by deviceid, readdate, grp
           -- having mx > mn + 1 * interval '1 hour'
```

Is there a way to return back the deviceid with it's max size? I am trying to find the longest continuous hourly readings

the data looks like this:

```
    deviceid    readdate
91428   2018-08-27 18:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 17:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 16:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 12:04:42
91428   2018-08-27 11:04:42
91428   2018-08-26 20:04:42
91428   2018-08-26 17:04:40
91428   2018-08-26 16:04:40
91428   2018-08-26 15:04:40
91428   2018-08-26 12:04:40
91489   2018-08-26 06:00:49
91493   2018-08-27 06:58:44
91511   2018-08-27 12:57:01
91511   2018-08-27 10:57:01
91511   2018-08-27 09:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 23:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 22:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 20:57:01
91511   2018-08-26 13:56:59
91511   2018-08-26 12:56:59
91511   2018-08-26 10:56:59
91547   2018-08-26 16:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 15:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 14:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 11:59:07
91547   2018-08-26 04:59:07
91582   2018-08-27 12:01:45
91582   2018-08-26 19:01:45
```

in this example: 91428  would have a max size of 3 since the largest size for id 91428 is 18:04:42 / 17:04:42 / 16:04:42

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Just did, sorry getting used to the structures for questions

Answer (score 0):

The way you're asking the question is a little confusing, the "island" and "max size" terminology must be specific to your industry, but would this sort of brute-force approach help? The format here is:

deviceid  , 1st reading, gap to next reading, 2nd reading, gap to next, etc

I commented out my criteria "WHERE   gap1 = '01:00:00'  AND   gap2  =  '01:00:00' ", but that would find your consecutive hourly readings.

```
WITH DEVICEID_TEST_DATA   AS


(     SELECT  CAST(91428  AS  bigint) AS deviceid   ,  CAST('2018-08-27 18:04:42' AS TIMESTAMP)  AS readdate UNION
      SELECT  91428     ,   '2018-08-27 17:04:42'         UNION
      SELECT  91428     ,   '2018-08-27 16:04:42'         UNION
      SELECT  91428     ,   '2018-08-27 12:04:42'         UNION
      SELECT  91428     ,   '2018-08-27 11:04:42'         UNION
      SELECT  91428     ,   '2018-08-26 20:04:42'         UNION
      SELECT  91428     ,   '2018-08-26 17:04:40'         UNION
      SELECT  91428     ,   '2018-08-26 16:04:40'         UNION
      SELECT  91428     ,   '2018-08-26 15:04:40'         UNION
      SELECT  91428     ,   '2018-08-26 12:04:40'         UNION
      SELECT  91489     ,   '2018-08-26 06:00:49'         UNION
      SELECT  91493     ,   '2018-08-27 06:58:44'         UNION
      SELECT  91511     ,   '2018-08-27 12:57:01'         UNION
      SELECT  91511     ,   '2018-08-27 10:57:01'         UNION
      SELECT  91511     ,   '2018-08-27 09:57:01'         UNION
      SELECT  91511     ,   '2018-08-26 23:57:01'         UNION
      SELECT  91511     ,   '2018-08-26 22:57:01'         UNION
      SELECT  91511     ,   '2018-08-26 20:57:01'         UNION
      SELECT  91511     ,   '2018-08-26 13:56:59'         UNION
      SELECT  91511     ,   '2018-08-26 12:56:59'         UNION
      SELECT  91511     ,   '2018-08-26 10:56:59'         UNION
      SELECT  91547     ,   '2018-08-26 16:59:07'         UNION
      SELECT  91547     ,   '2018-08-26 15:59:07'         UNION
      SELECT  91547     ,   '2018-08-26 14:59:07'         UNION
      SELECT  91547     ,   '2018-08-26 11:59:07'         UNION
      SELECT  91547     ,   '2018-08-26 04:59:07'         UNION
      SELECT  91582     ,   '2018-08-27 12:01:45'         UNION
      SELECT  91582     ,   '2018-08-26 19:01:45'


)


SELECT  *     FROM   (

SELECT  deviceid ,  readdate  ,   
readdate - (LAG(readdate, 1)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC) ) AS gap1  ,
LAG(readdate, 1)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC) AS  readdate_1down  ,
(LAG(readdate, 1)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC)) - (LAG(readdate, 2)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC))    AS   gap2  ,
LAG(readdate, 2)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC) AS  readdate_2down ,
(LAG(readdate, 2)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC)) - (LAG(readdate, 3)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC))    AS   gap3  ,
LAG(readdate, 3)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC) AS  readdate_3down  ,
(LAG(readdate, 3)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC)) - (LAG(readdate, 4)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC))    AS   gap4  ,
LAG(readdate, 4)  OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid  ORDER BY  readdate ASC) AS  readdate_4down
FROM  DEVICEID_TEST_DATA
-------WHERE   deviceid  =  91428

)
--------WHERE   gap1 = '01:00:00'  AND   gap2  =  '01:00:00'
ORDER BY  deviceid  ,  readdate DESC
```

Comment: A better way to solve it is a sliding window and calculating the differences from there

Comment: That approach would work but it's limited to 4. If it changes to 5 or 6 then more rows would need to be added